# How to use sed to remove "(double-quotes) on code lines while leaving them on real comment lines in a vimrc file?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, vim, sed, awk

On Ubuntu(Server/Desktop), I wish to remove a single `"` (double quotes) character from the beginning of lines in my `/etc/vim/vimrc`.

This should be done for all lines that start with a `"`, but not if the `"` is followed by a *single* space character, since the latter indicate *real* comments (as opposed to commented code). My goal is to toggle the commented code by removing the starting `"`, while leaving the rest fo the file unaltered.

BEFORE:

```
" Vim will load $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim if the user does not have a vimrc.
" This happens after /etc/vim/vimrc(.local) are loaded, so it will override
" any settings in these files.
" If you don't want that to happen, uncomment the below line to prevent
" defaults.vim from being loaded.
" let g:skip_defaults_vim = 1

" Uncomment the next line to make Vim more Vi-compatible
" NOTE: debian.vim sets 'nocompatible'.  Setting 'compatible' changes numerous
" options, so any other options should be set AFTER setting 'compatible'.
"set compatible

" Vim5 and later versions support syntax highlighting. Uncommenting the next
" line enables syntax highlighting by default.
if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif

" If using a dark background within the editing area and syntax highlighting
" turn on this option as well
"set background=dark

" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
"if has("autocmd")
"  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
"endif
```

AFTER:

```
" Vim will load $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim if the user does not have a vimrc.
" This happens after /etc/vim/vimrc(.local) are loaded, so it will override
" any settings in these files.
" If you don't want that to happen, uncomment the below line to prevent
" defaults.vim from being loaded.
" let g:skip_defaults_vim = 1

" Uncomment the next line to make Vim more Vi-compatible
" NOTE: debian.vim sets 'nocompatible'.  Setting 'compatible' changes numerous
" options, so any other options should be set AFTER setting 'compatible'.
"set compatible

" Vim5 and later versions support syntax highlighting. Uncommenting the next
" line enables syntax highlighting by default.
if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif

" If using a dark background within the editing area and syntax highlighting
" turn on this option as well
set background=dark

" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif
```

DIFF:

```
~$ diff BEFORE.out AFTER.out 
21c21
< "set background=dark
---
> set background=dark
25,27c25,27
< "if has("autocmd")
< "  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
< "endif
---
> if has("autocmd")
>   au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
> endif
```

Please note that if there is indented code, the starting `"` would be followed by a number of space characters greater than one: I want to uncomment those lines, too, while preserving the indentation.

I figured out how to get things working with the following command:

```
$ sudo sed -i.orig '/^\" [a-zA-Z]\|^"set compatible\|^\" let g:skip_defaults_vim = 1b/! s/^\"//' /etc/vim/vimrc
```

Can this be done better(cleaner/tighter/etc.)?

Can this also be done using `awk` for the same result?

Comment: You might be able to improve this question , there are loads of problems with it but we get the message "
 Chris Rainey is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct.  https://superuser.com/conduct"     So hopefully somebody can reply to you re that but it'd take me too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substitution command is very simple:

```
sed -r 's/^"(\S|\s{2,})/\1/' /etc/vim/vimrc
```

Or similarly in Perl:

```
perl -lape 's/^"(\S|\s{2,})/\1/' /etc/vim/vimrc
```

And AWK:

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/^"(\S|\s{2,})/,"\\1",1)}1' /etc/vim/vimrc
```

---

In your example, you seem to be specifying exceptions for lines that contain certain strings.
This is not explained in your text, but could be added as a condition:

```
sed -r '/^"set compatible/! s/^"(\S|\s{2,})/\1/' /etc/vim/vimrc
perl -lape 's/^"(\S|\s{2,})/\1/ if!/^"set compatible/' /etc/vim/vimrc
awk '!/^"set compatible/ {$0=gensub(/^"(\S|\s{2,})/,"\\1",1)}1' /etc/vim/vimrc
```